# Error when retrieving the history list from Gmail.Users.history.list API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm trying to retrieve the history list and to find out the newly added messages using Gmail API. I'm using Google scripts to do this.

Here's the watch request that I have defined. I assign the historyId of the response to **histId** variable.

```html
var watchResource = Gmail.newWatchRequest();
  watchResource.labelIds = ["INBOX"];
  watchResource.labelFilterAction = "include";
  watchResource.topicName = "projects/project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxx/topics/gmailTrigger";
  
  var response = Gmail.Users.watch(watchResource, userId);
  var histId = response.historyId;
```

And I'm using this method to get the history list.

```html
var his = Gmail.Users.History.list(userId,{'startHistoryId': histId});
Logger.log(his);
```

When I use the **histId** variable as a parameter to the 'startHistoryId', It should send me the history list of my inbox. But it doesn't give me the expected output.

Expected output - "{historyId=7092010, history=[{messagesAdded=[{message={threadId=16xxxxxxxxxf, labelIds=[UNREAD, CATEGORY_FORUMS, Label_24593xxxxxxxxxx7]}"

Output that I get - "{historyId=7092010}"

But when I hardcode the historyId that I receive from the response (response.historyId) to the above code, It gives me the expected output.

```html
var his = Gmail.Users.History.list(userId,{startHistoryId: 7092010});
Logger.log(his);
```

Can someone help me with this? I need to use the variable without hardcoding it.

Comment: Try ```histId*1```

Comment: I tried it now. Still getting the same output @I'-'I

Comment: I can't reproduce... I don't have Pub/Sub set up (for watches, etc), so I grabbed a history ID for a recent thread: `var startId = Gmail.Users.Threads.get("me", "some thread id", {fields: "historyId"}).historyId` and then used it as `Gmail.Users.History.list("me", {startHistoryId: startId})` and got both the latest `historyId` and a list of changes since that thread arrived.

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both but still getting the same output. The only difference it gets is that when multiplying by 1, it produces the history ID along with a decimal point. `histId = 7199925.0`

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the input. I'll give it try

Comment: Is it possible that the history is not updated.. say, If you're calling soon after the watch notification... maybe sleep a few minutes before the list call?

Comment: @I'-'I Yes. That was the problem. Since I'm directly calling the API and getting the history ID, it sends me the history ID at that moment. I'm not getting any messages in the output because there are no messages for the current ID at that moment. Thank you so much for your input. :)

Comment: Hi @ShanikaPerera I am having the same issue. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you setup gmail push notifications, you need to call a `watch()` method as [described in the Gmail API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). That method returns a historyId value. That's the current history ID at the time you started subscribing to push notifications. When a push notification arrives, it contains the new "current history ID" value. If you try to get updates *since* (i.e. updates after) the most recent/current history ID value, by definition there will always be nothing (because there is nothing after the most recent change). So what you need to do is check for updates since the last time you fetched updates.

So for example, the first time you call watch and receive an update, you'll want to get changes since you initially called watch (i.e. you'll get changes since the `historyId` value returned by the watch subscription). After getting those updates, you'll want to save the "current history ID" value returned by that push notification so you know the last history ID you've synced. When you get a new push notification, you'll fetch updates since the historyId of the last push notification, etc.

I was confused by this as well (I feel like the docs could be a bit clearer i. Hopefully this helps someone.